# Axis2 problem with signature verification - probably caused by HTML character references

Tags: java, xml, encoding, apache-axis, digital-signature

I have used Axis2 to built a client for WebService using message signing (service run on Websphere).

Client works fine but in some cases service sends response containing HTML character references (for polish national characters - for example `&#322;`) and then signature verification failed.

I found after some research that xml parser used by axis changes HTML character references to UTF-8 characters when parsing and this may be a reason of failure.

Has anyone had similar issue or has some idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

During parsing, XML text content is converted to Java Strings, which b.t.w. uses the UTF-16 encoding. To get consistent results, XML signature requires XML canonicalization which requires that the XML document is encoded in a UTF-8 character stream.

Nothing of this suggests that the character reference is the source of the error. I would rather search for an inconsistency between suggested encodings (in SOAP payload, in HTTP headers, etc) and non-ascii characters that are not encoded using character references.

Comment: Sorry, of course java String use UTF-16, my mistake.

I know that canonicalization is done and document is converted to UTF-8 I even debug whole signature preparing process.

When body contain Fault verification process fails. Only difference between working and error transmission is that polish national characters as HTML character references. In normal working response polish characters are encoded in UTF-8 and verification works successfully.

Both headers in working and not working response has the same encoding text/xml:charset=UTF-8 they differ only in HTTP status.